error during build: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
I am getting an error when I run npm run build in production
error during build:
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at RegExp.exec (<anonymous>)
at file:///var/www/html/test.webapp/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-52909643.js:37177:54
at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
at _interpolate (file:///var/www/html/test.webapp/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-52909643.js:37176:18)
at file:///var/www/html/test.webapp/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-52909643.js:37210:15
at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
at _interpolate (file:///var/www/html/test.webapp/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-52909643.js:37176:18)
at file:///var/www/html/test.webapp/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-52909643.js:37210:15
at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
at _interpolate (file:///var/www/html/test.webapp/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-52909643.js:37176:18)


I have already checked every function that might be causing an infinite loop
I have already checked for circular dependencies between files or modules that might be causing this issue.

